# How to download file in android webview from direct download link

Tags: android, webview, download

I want to download file using webview in android  from direct download link. like [LINK HERE](https://github.com/dideler/android-calculator/archive/master.zip).

Into my application I have the direct download link and when I press download button that perform the download function. write now I able to download file using **defalut browser** but default browser display the url, i don't want to display url because it contains the secured **userID** and other details...

In short I have url, when I run this url into system browser it direct download file. same url i want call into android app and download file into **sdcard**, but do not shaw url to customer.

Please Help me.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have the url already than just download the page from that url using a http client and save content to file. You really have the url and can cancel the invoke of the default browser? Where do you grab the url?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DownloadManager class for this purpose, it will manage all your downloads and show notifications. Also the URL will be hidden from the user.

Comment: here is the code, hoping it would help http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/11/download-file-videoaudiotext-through.html

Comment: Thanks, but  DownloadManager class return html page instead of image...  any idea?

Comment: i have url of the image download file

Comment: can you give the link here?

Comment: it's secure link with userid and password of client's purchased product... so i can't share  it but when i run link on browser i can able to download file success.

Comment: does that link open after a POST or GET query using a form? can you post the html page that you get?

Comment: yes our webpage is posted on other page, that's why html is displayed in our response.

Comment: Hi i have similar issue. was this issue solve?? @Somil